# Values don't leave the stack after Pop (Stack<T>)

Tags: c#, list, generics, stack

The stack is formed from a list that was grouped. Then there are several foreachs where `Pop` is called.
But the number of values in the stacks does not decrease.
Please explain why. Thank you in advance!

```
    public static void N(){
    var test = new List<int>(){1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8};
    var testGr = test.GroupBy(x=>x);

    var stacked = testGr.Select(x=> new {
        num = x.Key,
        stack = new Stack<int>(x)
    });

    var testNumOne = stacked.First(x=>x.num==1);        
    Console.WriteLine(testNumOne.stack.Count());

    foreach(var x in new List<int>(){1,2,1,2,3}){
        var flush = stacked.First(y => y.num == x).stack.Pop();
    }

    testNumOne = stacked.First(x=>x.num==1);        
    Console.WriteLine(testNumOne.stack.Count());
}
```

Comment: LINQ is effectively a view. Your stack is a projection. Each time you iterate through `stacked`, you create a new stack from `test`.

Comment: Also in `stack = new Stack<int>(x.Select(t=>t).ToList())` you don't need `.Select(t=>t)`, `new Stack<int>(x.ToList())` should be enough.

Comment: `new Stack<int>(x)` should be enough. It takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is what `x` is.

Comment: @GuruStron In fact `ToList()` is also superfluous; it should be simply `new Stack<int>(x)`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay agreed)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't pay attention to "foreach's kitchen", we all just learn all the time) I'd edited my question

Comment: @Genka Your edit doesn't change the problem. Each time you call `stacked.First()`, you are creating a **new** `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

The copy of "stacked" solves the problem (through stacked.ToList())

```
public static void Main()
{  
    var test = new List<int>(){1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8};
    var testGr = test.GroupBy(x=>x);

    var stacked = testGr.Select(x=> new {
        num = x.Key,
        stack = new Stack<int>(x)
    });
    var stackedCopy = stacked.ToList();
    var testNumOne = stackedCopy.First(x=>x.num==1);        
    Console.WriteLine(testNumOne.stack.Count());

    foreach(var x in new List<int>(){1,2,1,2,3}){
        var flush = stackedCopy.First(y => y.num == x).stack.Pop();
    }

    testNumOne = stackedCopy.First(x=>x.num==1);        
    Console.WriteLine(testNumOne.stack.Count());
}
```

I'm already learning how the Linq library works with memory. Thank you all very much!)